# Java testing framework for testing new shim gives same results as old api?

Tags: library, java, unit-tests

I'm working to take an old no longer supported, but still heavily used throughout my company, library and create a replacement shim that passes all the real work down to a different library that is supported.

To make sure we have done this right I'm going to need a number of unit tests that will run the same commands against the old library and the new shim and verify the exact same responses come back.  I could of course write these tests manually, but I'm wondering if there is an already existing testing tools that might remove some of the boilerplate for testing against two versions of the same API to confirm they give identical results.

Comment: Calling two identical methods isn't a big problem in Java, that can be handled easily using proxy pattern that Java supports [out of the box](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies). But the major problem that remains and that can not be solved by a library is to define the input test data. Even capturing real world examples as input test data may be not enough to cover corner cases.